# adding validation to dynamically created input fields w/ unique names

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form for inputting information about check and cash payments for when my employees make a bank deposit. In the event that there are multiple check and/or cash payments in the deposit, the user can click a button to add additional fields. The function the button calls also changes the id and name of the additional fields by increasing a number.

I'm having trouble seeing how I could add bootstrap validation to these additional fields since the ids are all unique.

the form:

```
<form id="depositForm" name="depositForm" method="post" action="deposit.php">

              <div class="form-group" id="checks">  
                <h3>Check 1:</h3>
                <div class="row" id="check_1">

                    <div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10">
                    <label for="checkInvoiceNumber_1" class="control-label">Invoice #:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkInvoiceNumber_1" name="checkInvoiceNumber_1" placeholder="Enter Invoice # payment is for"/>
                    </div> 

                    <div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10">
                    <label for="checkNumber_1" class="control-label">Check #:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkNumber_1" name="checkNumber_1" placeholder="Enter Check #"/>
                    </div> 

                    <div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10">
                    <label for="checkAmount_1" class="control-label">Check Amount:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkAmount_1" name="checkAmount_1" placeholder="Enter $Amount of Check"/>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row padding-top-10" align="center" >
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_check()" onClick="addCheck()" value="Add Check"/>
              </div> 

              <div class="form-group" id="cash">  
                <h3>Cash Payment 1:</h3>
                <div class="row" id="cash_1">

                    <div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10">
                    <label for="invoiceNumber" class="control-label">Invoice #:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="invoiceNumber_1" name="invoiceNumber_1"placeholder="Enter Invoice # payment is for"/>
                    </div> 

                    <div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10">
                    <label for="cashAmount" class="control-label">Cash Amount:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cashAmount_1" name="cashAmount_1" placeholder="Enter $Amount of Cash"/>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row padding-top-10" align="center" >
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_cash()" onClick="addCash()" value="Add Cash"/>
              </div> 

              <div class="row padding-top-10" align="center" >
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Deposit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

The javascript to add additional check fields with increasing IDs/names:

```
function addCheck()
{
    check_i++;
    var checkDiv = document.createElement('div');
    checkDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>Check '+check_i+':</h3><div class="row" id="check_'+check_i+'"><div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10"><label for="checkInvoiceNumber_'+check_i+'" class="control-label">Invoice #:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkInvoiceNumber_'+check_i+'" name="checkInvoiceNumber_'+check_i+'" placeholder="Enter Invoice # payment is for"/></div><div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10"><label for="checkNumber_'+check_i+'" class="control-label">Check #:</label><input type="text" class="form-control"id="checkNumber_'+check_i+'" name="checkNumber_'+check_i+'" placeholder="Enter Check #"/></div><div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10"><label for="checkAmount_'+check_i+'" class="control-label">Check Amount:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkAmount_'+check_i+'" name="checkAmount_'+check_i+'" placeholder="Enter $Amount of Check"/></div></div>';
    document.getElementById('checks').appendChild(checkDiv);                
}
```

And a sample of the validation i'd like to apply to the form; In this case, the "checkAmount_n" field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var validator = $("#depositForm").bootstrapValidator({

        fields : {

            checkAmount_1 :{
                message : "The check amount is required",
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : "Please enter the check amount! Ex: 99.99"
                    },
                    numeric : {
                        message : "this must be a number! Ex: 99.99"
                    },
                    lessThan : {
                        value : 1000000,
                        message : "No way someone payed us over $1 million to do anything!"
                    },
                    greaterThan : {
                        value : 0.001,
                        message : "Surely we received at least 1 cent?"
                    }
                }
            }
```

The validation obviously works fine for the original field checkAmount_1, but how do i add validation to checkAmount_2, checkAmount_3, etc... as they're added by the button click?

If this is all stupid just let me know... I'm very new to programming and am clearly just hacking away at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addField` method of `bootstrapValidator` as used in following examples:

[dynamic.html](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/dynamic.html)

[dynamic2.html](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/dynamic2.html)

[dynamic3.html](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/dynamic3.html)

For your problem you can change your `addCheck` function as follows:

```
function addCheck()
{
    check_i++;
    var checkDiv = document.createElement('div');
    checkDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>Check '+check_i+':</h3><div class="row" id="check_'+check_i+'"><div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10"><label for="checkInvoiceNumber_'+check_i+'" class="control-label">Invoice #:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkInvoiceNumber_'+check_i+'" name="checkInvoiceNumber_'+check_i+'" placeholder="Enter Invoice # payment is for"/></div><div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10"><label for="checkNumber_'+check_i+'" class="control-label">Check #:</label><input type="text" class="form-control"id="checkNumber_'+check_i+'" name="checkNumber_'+check_i+'" placeholder="Enter Check #"/></div><div class = "col-md-4 padding-top-10"><label for="checkAmount_'+check_i+'" class="control-label">Check Amount:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkAmount_'+check_i+'" name="checkAmount_'+check_i+'" placeholder="Enter $Amount of Check"/></div></div>';
    document.getElementById('checks').appendChild(checkDiv);                
    $("#depositForm").bootstrapValidator('addField','checkAmount_'+check_i, {
        message: 'The check amount is required',
        validators: {
            notEmpty : {
                message : "Please enter the check amount! Ex: 99.99"
            },
            numeric : {
                message : "this must be a number! Ex: 99.99"
            },
            lessThan : {
                value : 1000000,
                message : "No way someone payed us over $1 million to do anything!"
            },
            greaterThan : {
                value : 0.001,
                message : "Surely we received at least 1 cent?"
            }
        }
    } );
}
```